# Flask - How do I read the raw body in a POST request when the content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: python, ajax, post, flask

Turns out that Flask sets `request.data` to an empty string if the content type of the request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Since I'm using a JSON body request, I just want to parse the json or force Flask to parse it and return `request.json`.

This is needed because changing the AJAX content type forces an HTTP OPTION request, which complicates the back-end.

How do I make Flask return the raw data in the request object?

Comment: Yep `flask.request.data.decode("utf-8")` blank, but I thought it was a client side problem. Thanks for confirming flask is doing this!  Wow omg 10 years later! this conversation really saved my biscuit today ! I was puzzled for a  few hours.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the post data via `request.form.keys()[0]` if content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

`request.form` is a [multidict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), whose keys contain the parsed post data.

Comment: It seems this was also the way to get the data our of a post to bottle. Just change request.form.keys()[0] to `list(request.forms.keys())[0]`. Thanks for finally solving hours of debugging!

Comment: Why does it work? It seems it should be just the first key of the dictionary parsed from the body, but it somehow returns the entire body?

Comment: Can someone please explain why the data is put into the form keys?

Comment: This does *not* give you all of the post data if the data contains `=` and `&` characters.

Comment: @Emil it should be form not forms.

Comment: Even though this works, I don't think it should be the accepted answer. The other two answers below offer much better approaches to code legibility and maintainability.

Comment: 2023. This is straight up wrong. The `[0]` doesn't reference to anything and gives to you a runtime error because `form.keys()` are in `key: value` pairs. `param1=value1&param2=value2` returns `ImmutableMultiDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])`

Comment: I would use `form.keys` and go from there to get the data you need. `get_data()` returns a byte stream, only useful if you're dealing with binary data.`

Answer (score 13):

Use `request.get_data()` to get the POST data.  This works independent of whether the data has content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. With the requests I'm getting, if I use `get_data()` I get an empty `bytes()`, but with the accepted answer's method (looking at the form keys) I get a bunch of data.

Comment: Yup me too, nothing in get_data(), but it seems ridiculous to do it as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want get the JSON when request is 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' you need "force" conversion to json like de code below:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/my-endpoint", methods = ['POST'])
def myEndpoint():

    requestJson = request.get_json(force=True)

    //TODO: do something....

    return requestJson


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Probably it is outdated now so it's not working

Answer (score 1):

main.py

```py
import json

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    mimetype = request.mimetype
    if mimetype == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        form = json.loads(next(iter(request.form.keys())))
    elif mimetype == 'multipart/form-data':
        form = dict(request.form)
    elif mimetype == 'application/json':
        form = request.json
    else:
        form = request.data.decode()
    print(mimetype, form, type(form))
    return form


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Test

```bash
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ --data "{\"a\":1, \"b\":2}"

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ -F a=1 -F b=2

curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:5000/ --data "{\"a\":1, \"b\":2}"
```

Result

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded {'a': 1, 'b': 2} <class 'dict'>
multipart/form-data {'a': '1', 'b': '2'} <class 'dict'>
application/json {'a': 1, 'b': 2} <class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it that way:

```
@app.route("/path-to-the-post-endpoint", methods=["POST"])
def handle_post_request():
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    data['some_key_1'] = "Some Value 1"
    data['some_key_2'] = "Some Value 2"
    # ...etc.

    # DO SOMETHING HERE

    return [], 200
```

Comment: My post request Content-Type was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I want to convert it to a dictionary. This worked for me `request.form.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
f = request.form

   output = []

   user_data = {}

   user_data['email'] = f['email']

   user_data['password'] = f['password']

   user_data['key'] = f['key']

   output.append(user_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.values` will obtain both `args` and `post`, proiritizing `args` per [Python docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Request.values)

`request.json` will handle a JSON payload.